# How does Hibernate manages transactions and data syncrhonization locks?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have an entity `User` in database. I want to understand how Hibernate/JPA transaction manages read/write lock on table data to avoid stale data.

For example:

1. Transaction `T1` reads `User` from database
2. Transaction `T2` deletes the same `User` from database

What will happen to the `User` read in `T1`?

Comment: The question is too broad. Actual behavior may vary depending on at least the transaction isolation level. Also the lock mode affects it. Please, clarify.

Comment: Transaction isolation level is READ_COMMITED

Comment: Then this is a typical `phantom read`. Hibernate does not do anything specific to prevent from that condition.

Answer (score 0):

for T1 he is still reading  the object till session is refreshed or object is evicted or object is deleted from garbage collection 
But for first operation with data base it will throw exception .

for T2 he can't read the object 
i hope my answer is useful for you

Comment: Here my question is, will hibernate or database lock will prevent T2 to delete the User object ? Because T1 has lock on User. If not, then this is really a dangerous situation that T1 has read User and its no more exist in T2, when T1 modifies it and try to save it back, Booom !

Comment: T1 does not acquire a lock on the entity unless instructed to do so, e.g. `LockMode.UPGRADE` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and reading few blogs, i found an interesting blog http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/hibernate/concurrency-control-with-hibernate-4/ which answers the question. Hibernate don't do anything special about locking and transaction management, it utilizes underlying database implementation for locking records. Though we can prevent such concurrent modification issues by using Optimistic locking and version control field by adding a version field with the entity. Every time this version gets incremented on update operation and rejects any entity with lower version then in the database to be updated.